# Disproving two decimal representation rebuttal of Cantor's Diagonal Argument

Tags: real-analysis

A question in my book has asked me the following:

> A few numbers have *two* difference decimal representations. Specifically, any decimal expansion that terminates can also be written with repeating 9's. For instance, $\frac{1}{2}$ can be written $.499999...$ or $0.5$ - doesn't this cause some problems?

I understand now that $.999999.... = 1$ because of the definition of a supremum on the set of $\{0.9, 0.99, 0.999, ...\}$ (the set of all decimal expansions of $0.9$). If there was a number smaller than 1 greater than this set - it would be that number.

However, in Cantor's Diagonalization Argument the assumption is that there is some $f: \mathbb{N} -> (0, 1)$, which is disproved by contradiction.

In this case, if we operate under that assumption, then each further decimal expansion of $0.9$ would be granted it's own natural number. So it wouldn't cause any problems with this proof under the assumption $f: \mathbb{N} -> (0, 1)$.

There would not be an assumption of $0.999999... = 1$ because even though the supremum of $(0, 1)$ is 1, there is not a $1$ in this set (otherwise it would be $(0, 1]$), and so it wouldn't be possible to consider any decimal expansion of $0.9$ equal to $1$ in the set $(0, 1)$ even though we get infinitely close to it.

Is this the correct line of thinking? To be honest I'm still wrapping my head around $0.99999... = 1$ so this threw me for a loop.

Comment: One way is to always choose the number in the $n$-th decimal place to be say $2$ or $7$. That avoids these ambiguous decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think it through.

Suppose you have an $f: \mathbb N\to (0,1)$.  (By the way, that *isn't* a contradiction if we don't assume $f$ is surjective.  We aren't trying to find a contradiction.  We are simply trying to find an $x \in (0, 1)$ so that there if no $n$ so that $f(n) = x$.)

We take a number so that $k$th digit of $x$ is *not* the $k$th digit of $f(k)$.  The idea being that $x$ will have a different integer from every output of $f$ and therefore is inequal to every output of $f$.

Now you are wondering what happens if our algorithm to find the $k$th digit of $x$ will yield an infinite number of $9$s and that this number is equal to some $f(n)$ that actually had an infinite number of $0$s.

Well.... then simply don't replace $0$ with $9$.  Replace $0$ with $8$, say, and $9$ with $7$ and so on.

Let's say our $x$ has a trailing bunch of $9$ starting in the $k$ position.  But $x = f(n)$ which has a trailing bunch of $0$ at and beyond the $k$th position.  Well $n < k$ because if $n\ge k$ then the $n$th digit of $x$ is $9$ so the $n$th position of $f(n) \ne 0$ which contradicts the nature of dual representations (a trailing $9$ is in the position of a trailing $0$).  But if $n<k$ then the $n$the digit of $x$ is *before* the trailing $9$s.  So that means if $x=f(n)$ and the $n$th digit of both of those representations are before the repeating $9$s then the $n$th digit of $f(n)$ and the $n$th digit of $x$ are the same.  But we selected $x$ so that would not be possible.

====

Perhaps a blunt way of doing this is to create $x$ by saying if the $n$th digit of $f(n)$ is *not* $7$ then then $n$th digit of $x$ *is* $7$.  And if the $n$th digit of $f(n)$ is $7$ then the $n$th digit of $x$ is $6$.

Then $x$ will only have $6$s and $7$s in its decimal representations and there is no dual representation possible for $x$.  So it will not be possible for $x$ to be equal to $f(n)$ for some $n$ in a different representation.

Answer (score 2):

Simply restrict to a unique representation for each real number.  Don't allow any infinite sequence of $9$'s to occur, say.

Then proceed with the argument.

Answer (score 0):

What is usually presented as Cantor's diagonal argument, is not what Cantor argued. (See http://www.logicmuseum.com/cantor/diagarg.htm).

The most glaring misrepresentation is that it used real numbers. It intentionally did not. The set it used was the set of all infinite-length strings made of two characters. However, with Chris Custer's restrictions, it can work with the decimal representations of [0,1). So this misrepresentation is not very critical.

But the next one is. Cantor never assumed he had a surjective function f:N→(0,1). What diagonlaization proves - directly, and not by contradiction - is that any such function cannot be surjective. The contradiction he talked about, was that a listing can't be complete, and non-surjective, at the same time.

Comment: Huh, weird. My book - _Understanding Analysis_  implies this is solved via a contradiction. In particular that $x \ne f(n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ shows that a contradiction exists leading to $(0, 1)$ being uncountable.

Comment: I know. Too many books do. It probably starts by assuming the equivalent of a bijective function f:N→(0,1). But then it only uses the fact that it is a function to derive an element that isn't listed. Since it doesn't use "bijective" in any way, any contradiction found says nothing about "bijective." But if you look at what Cantor actually said (in the link), no such assumption is made.

Comment: Thats exactly what the book did. I will read more on this - interesting!

Comment: I just want to add a comment about proof by contradiction. Say you want to prove the statement (~A or ~B) using it. So you assume the opposite, (A and B), and show that it leads to a contradiction. But the contradiction only disproves the part of the assumption that was used in the derivation. When diagonalization is presented as a proof-by-contradiction, it is in this form (A=a lists exists, B=that list is complete), but iit doesn't derive anything from assuming B. Only A. This is what people object to, even if they don't realize it. But it shows that A->~B; any list is incomplete.